# Would 12.04 work well on my VAIO with single core 1.86GHz Centrino and 1GB RAM?

Tags: 12.04, 10.04, intel, vaio

Used to run on 10.04, dualbooted. Hard drive got replaced and now I have a blank piece of paper to work with.

What system do you recommend?

My laptop: Sony VAIO VGN-FJ270

- CPU: 1.86 GHz [Pentium M 750](http://ark.intel.com/products/27593/Intel-Pentium-M-Processor-750-2M-Cache-1_86-GHz-533-MHz-FSB)
- RAM: 1 GB
- VGA: Intel Graphics Media Accelerator 900, 128 MB
- Chipset: Intel 915GM

Source: [Specification](http://www.docs.sony.com/release/specs/vgn-fj270b_spec.pdf), [Support Page](http://esupport.sony.com/US/p/model-home.pl?mdl=VGNFJ270&LOC=3&session_id=6ccb74077344a894849dc45bbd2b29f1#/manualsTab)

Comment: use a live cd/usb and see how it works (IO atleast should be slower than a HD installation)

Answer (score 1):

I will not recommend this. Actually I had such setup before and in case I reach top memory the usability went down. Try to add maximum memory you can. Then it could go somehow, depending on what you need to run. Otherwise I will recommend to use 12.04 Xubuntu or Lubuntu, which does not use Unity and therefore are less demanding to system resources. But you will loose some comfort Unity has.

Comment: Lubuntu 12.04 has only an 18 month term of support that is until October, 2013.

Comment: @Karel: I use xubuntu with no major problems... but you can install xcfe to ubuntu and use different desktop as well, but its not straightforward solution.

Answer (score 1):

Personally I would not even try Ubuntu with a single core pentium.  Ubuntu and Kubuntu will be way too slow as will Gnome Remix.

You may be OK with [Xubuntu](http://xubuntu.org/getxubuntu/) however but I would recommend  [Lubuntu](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Lubuntu/GetLubuntu) it  runs on almost any hardware. Lubuntu is not an LTS release so I would go with the latest 13.04.

Make sure you have a good set of backups first.

Try it from a live USB/CD then assuming you have no problems install. You can restore your personal data from the backup.

Both Xubuntu and Lubuntu are official Ubuntu releases and supported here, [Launchpad](https://answers.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+questions) and on the [Ubuntu Forums](http://ubuntuforums.org/forum.php)

Comment: Kubuntu might actually work, if you disable compositing in KDE settings.

Answer (score 0):

Try [13.04, Raring Ringtail](http://releases.ubuntu.com/raring/). I do seem to notice a slight performance boost [on my legacy quad-core AMD] and suspect you may get something similar out of your Intel Core Duo. Everything is a little more snappy.

Comment: Noah's Intel Pentium M 750 is a single core CPU.

Comment: Ah, I saw Core Duo somewhere, but have just confirmed you are correct. Maybe there will be a performance issue, but the [System Requirements](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/SystemRequirements) do not specify a required number of cores in their requirements. I feel like I can remember installing Ubuntu on single core Shuttles back in the day.

Comment: not worth even a try... sorry. Memory would be main performance problem here, followed by multitasking on one core from several apps vs. kernel and system services at once. 13.04 will not change anything on that. Solution is to lower system consumtion of memory and CPU, which is significant on Unity basic setup in comaprison with LXDE's or XFCE's basic setups.

Answer (score 0):

Your computer will do a "good" work if we use "Single task with enough time to finish each task" as a synonym of "good" BUT JUST if you use a lightweight desktop environment, such as XFCE.

Other users have recommended the usage of XUbuntu or Lubuntu but I would go for a plain install of Ubuntu 12.04 and after the painful installation of the operating system, I would invest some time to install XCFE Desktop Environment by dropping `sudo apt-get install xfce4` in a terminal. This command will  install only the Desktop Environment, leaving the rest as-is.

The next steps will be to start learning how to log into XFCE by choosing the proper Desktop Environment from the list in the login screen and -of course- get familiar to the new Desktop Environment.

I have tested myself this in a single core component with 1 GB RAM and it does a good work when browsing the net, watching movies (even online), doing some programming, working in documents, spreadsheets, etc. The problem starts when you wish to be doing several things at once. In example: having more than 3 tabs opened in Google-Chrome, listening to music, chatting in facebook chat and working in a document at once. Several things at once will reduce the speed on which the things works on your computer.

Having that in consideration I would go for the 12.04 LTS and XFCE.

I am aware that there are other lightweight Desktop Environments such as LXDE but if you are looking for stability I suggest you to stay in XFCE.

Good luck!

Comment: for a beginner its not an easy and straightforward way...

Comment: The user seems not to be a "beginner". He clearly states he "Used to run on 10.04 dualbooted" which sounds kinda some experienced.